# How to enable IP lookup - enableLookups in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

On Tomcat there is an attribute `"enableLookups"` to enable IP lookup. I have a program which we have migrated from Tomcat to Spring MVC and I am not getting any idea where can I set this atrribute.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/something")
    public String something(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
         String someVar = request.getRemoteHost();
.....
.......
```

`request.getRemoteHost()` - returns IP Address instead of host name.

Answer (score 1):

If your Spring Boot application is configured to use an embedded application server, use the `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` facility to configure the server according to your needs. Some hints specific to Tomcat as embedded server are given in the [official Spring Boot guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-webserver):

```
@Component
public class TomcatServerCustomizer
    implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory) {
        TomcatConnectorCustomizer customizer = connector -> connector.setEnableLookups(true);
        tomcatServletWebServerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers(customizer);
    }
}
```

Note, `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` is available since Spring Boot 2.0.0.